# How to check if Chromium OS vulnerable to Dirty COW?

Tags: google-compute-engine, vulnerabilities, chrome-os

I'm running some projects on Kubernetes clusters on the Google Compute Engine. The nodes which form the cluster run on Container-VM, a Chromium OS based image specifically designed for nodes on GCE. Logging onto one of the nodes and issuing a `uname -a` yields:

```
Linux <machine_name> 4.4.21+ #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 21:46:36 PDT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Question is, how can I detect if this kernel is still vulnerable to [Dirty COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_COW)? I googled a lot but I couldn't find any information. Even the Google forums on Chromium OS are empty. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes v1.4.5 has been build and pushed which has the patch for Dirty COW (CVE-2016-5195) vulnerability. You can refer to [kubernetes-announce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-announce/1EQk7UlN320) group for more information.